# C# Word Mail Merge using Wingdings font

Tags: c#, fonts, automation, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a Winform application in C# that is doing mail merge from a DataGridView.
I need to merge a checked/unchecked box for a Boolean cell.

```
    String strPresent;
    char EmptyBox = (char)0xA8;
    char CheckedBox = (char)0x254;
    Boolean bPresent = (Boolean)selectedRow.Cells["Present"].Value;
    if (bPresent)
        strPresent = CheckedBox.ToString();
    else
        strPresent = EmptyBox.ToString();
```

In the Word mergefields processing code:

```
    case "Present":
        myMergeField.Select();
        wordApp.Selection.TypeText(strPresent);
        wordApp.Selection.MoveLeft(WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1, WdMovementType.wdExtend);
```

Everything works to this point:
The problem is the checkbox is formatted Calibri (Body), not Wingdings.

```
    wordApp.Selection.Font.Name = "Wingdings";
    break;
```

The mergefield in the template is already formatted as Wingdings.
I have tried * charformat instead of * mergeformat in the template.
I have added a trailing underscore and a space to prevent the Selection.TypeText from selecting the whole paragraph.
Making the Word process visible, I can see the correct character is selected.

I've also tried:

```
                        Range myRange = wordApp.Selection.Range;
                        myRange.Font.Name = "Wingdings";
```

Comment: It's not apparent this has anything to do with mailmerge, since you're trying to select and overwrite a mergefield. Rather, it appears you're merely (mis)using mergefields as placeholders for an entirely different kind of automation. Messing with  \\* charformat and \\* mergeformat isn't going to help at all if you're overwriting the field.

Comment: It's exactly how numerous sources suggest how to do mail merge. See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/word-automation-using-C-Sharp/ or https://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2012/08/25/create-a-word-document-from-a-template-using-c-mail-merge/

Comment: Regardless of what your sources say, what you're doing *is not* a mailmerge; it is merely document automation pretending to be a mailmerge. When you do a *real* mailmerge, the mailmerge fields get their data directly from the data source via an ADODB connection, for example, without the need for any C# or VBA code. See, for example: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mail-merge-to-send-access-data-to-word-053cc639-fe30-4d3a-943d-0bee0892f16a & https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/data-sources-you-can-use-for-a-mail-merge-9de322a6-f0f9-448d-a113-5fab317d9ef4

Comment: That's if I had a simple data source that could utilize Excel or Access. I suppose I could take this approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-word-mail-merge-using-visual-c  However, my problem now is simply with the font, not with automation or mail merge.

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing this:

```
    char EmptyBox = (char)0xA8;
    char CheckedBox = (char)0x254;
```

to this:

```
    char EmptyBox = Char.Parse("\u2610");
    char CheckedBox = Char.Parse("\u2611");
```

and now I see a checkbox, but it appears narrow horizontally?
[image]

Comment: This solved the problem after I removed the Wingding font in the template. This was some good advice: https://www.penwatch.net/cms/checkmark/